# How can I reset Xcode's list of docsets?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I tried downloading docsets in Xcode 5, but something went wrong with the 10.9 docset.  I only needed the Xcode and iOS docsets, but the 10.9 set was added automatically.  The download is stalled at halfway.

I see docsets in these locations:

- ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/ (I also see bom and plist receipts there)
- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/

Questions:

- Why are there 2 docset locations?  Which does Xcode use?
- If I just delete everything in both directories, will Xcode refresh its docsets?

Comment: Why not just (backup and) try?